# How to load all specific cultures on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I'm working on a financial application and I want show all currency to user, but I don't know how to get all cultures. I see some way do that but don't any work with Windows Phone. Anyone have another way?

This is one way but not work on Windows Phone 8.1  :(

```
CultureInfo[] allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
```

Thank you.

Comment: For you case, I think it doesn't make sense to get all cultures. You need show all currency not all culture, culture and currency are not exactly matched.